# Type of systems that do not store state but the events that lead to it

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking for the name of this way of designing systems. I think the term is not very popular, I am not able to remember or find it.

It is about systems that replay a set of events or modifications to recover the state instead of storing the state itself.

Comment: FRP uses patterns resembling what you mean, more or less. It is described as *compositional events* system (family of systems).

Comment: In *version control* you can store either complete versions or *deltas*, and apply a sequence of deltas from one version to obtain another version — either forward or backward. Maybe there's a term in the field that fits what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) which is used to store events. Often you will find a stack associated which stores the commands. This can be seen in systems that which to undo events/commands.

Then you can undo the event and go back to a desired/previous state.

Answer (score 0):

Memento pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern

or

Finite state machine

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern

Comment: The memento pattern does not need to be implemented storing a sequence of steps. The same can be said about the state pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It's called [Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html).